# XML namespace defaulting/inheritance

Tags: java, xml

In the below XML snippet what are the namespaces of a, c, d and e? Reference to documentation or specifications would be appreciated.

```
<a xmlns="http://domain/a">
    <pre:b xmlns:pre="http://domain/b">
        <c/>
        <d xmlns="">
            <e/>
        </d>
    </pre:b>
</a>
```

Also, what Java frameworks respect the official namespace defaulting? I have tride org.w2c.* DOM packages, however it does not seem to resolve the namespace URI correctly? For example, something with similar functionality to.

```
String namespace = DocumentParser.parse().
                    getElement("a").
                    getElement("b").
                    getElement("c").
                    getNamespaceURI();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, all the standard XML APIs in Java support namespaces. Many of the APIs were written before namespaces were created (or became popular - I can no longer remember). You often need to [enable support](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)):

```
public class NS {
  private static void print(Node node) {
    Queue<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    nodes.add(node);
    while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
      node = nodes.poll();
      NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
      for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        nodes.add(list.item(i));
      }
      System.out.format("%s %s %s%n", node.getPrefix(), node.getLocalName(),
          node.getNamespaceURI());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<a xmlns=\"http://domain/a\">"
        + "<pre:b xmlns:pre=\"http://domain/b\">" + "<c/>" + "<d xmlns=\"\">"
        + "<e/>" + "</d>" + "</pre:b>" + "</a>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
        new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    print(doc.getDocumentElement());
  }
}
```

This code will print:

```
null a http://domain/a
pre b http://domain/b
null c http://domain/a
null d null
null e null
```

Answer (score 13):

From what I can tell it would be as follows.

- a will be http://domain/a as that is the default namespace
- b will be http://domain/b as that is the defined namespace for b
- c will be http://domain/a as that is the default namespace
- d will be a blank/unset namespace due to re-setting of the namespace
- e will be a blank/unset namespace, since it is nested inside of the new declaration

I am basing this off of this [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping-defaulting).  Below is a summary quote to help as well.

> If there is a default namespace
>   declaration in scope, the expanded
>   name corresponding to an unprefixed
>   element name has the URI of the
>   default namespace as its namespace
>   name. If there is no default namespace
>   declaration in scope, the namespace
>   name has no value. The namespace name
>   for an unprefixed attribute name
>   always has no value. In all cases, the
>   local name is local part (which is of
>   course the same as the unprefixed name
>   itself).

Answer (score 8):

A namespace declared using `xmlns="..."` becomes the default for any elements within it (until  the default is then redeclared in a deeper element, of course). So you end up with:

- a uses http://domain/a (specified as a default)
- b uses http://domain/b (specified, but not a default)
- c uses http://domain/a (inherited from a)
- d has no namespace (specified as a new default)
- e has no namespace (inherited from d)

The relevant spec section is the XML names spec, [section 6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting):

> The scope of a default namespace
>   declaration extends from the beginning
>   of the start-tag in which it appears
>   to the end of the corresponding
>   end-tag, excluding the scope of any
>   inner default namespace declarations.
>   In the case of an empty tag, the scope
>   is the tag itself.
>
> A default namespace declaration
>   applies to all unprefixed element
>   names within its scope. Default
>   namespace declarations do not apply
>   directly to attribute names; the
>   interpretation of unprefixed
>   attributes is determined by the
>   element on which they appear.
>
> If there is a default namespace
>   declaration in scope, the expanded
>   name corresponding to an unprefixed
>   element name has the URI of the
>   default namespace as its namespace
>   name. If there is no default namespace
>   declaration in scope, the namespace
>   name has no value. The namespace name
>   for an unprefixed attribute name
>   always has no value. In all cases, the
>   local name is local part (which is of
>   course the same as the unprefixed name
>   itself).